# Undesired result from SQL query in C# console application

Tags: c#, sql, desktop-application, sqlcommand

In my C# application I am trying to read data within my **Accounts** table, read the data as a decimal, preform a a calculation on it, and then update the same row.

Right now it reads the correct data in the column but two things go wrong when trying to update.

It sets all of the data in the **AccountTotal** column to the same value. This value is correct for the first row, but incorrect for the rest.

I believe the second problems occurs in calculating the data that is to be updated. When I try to update the DB, it sets the value twice as high as I am wanting it to be. For example: In my **CalculateIncome** method I wan't to add 100 to the account total, It adds 200.

What is causing these two problems?

Here is the program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Need to change when deploying on real database.
        const string DB_NAME = "Bank.sdf";
        const string DB_PATH = @"C:\Users\Lucas\eBankRepository\eBank\App_Data\" + DB_NAME; // Use ".\" for CWD or a specific path  
        const string CONNECTION_STRING = "Data Source=" + DB_PATH;

        decimal AccountTotal;

        var conn = new SqlCeConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
        SqlCeDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            //Basic Query of all accounts
            SqlCeCommand Query = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Accounts", conn);
            reader = Query.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                AccountTotal = reader.GetDecimal(2); //Column in DB for Account Total
                AccountTotal += CalculateIncome();

                //Update Total
                SqlCeCommand UpdateTotal = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Accounts SET AccountTotal = @UpdatedTotal", conn); // Error when using WHERE Clause "WHERE AccountName= @ Savings"
                UpdateTotal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdatedTotal", AccountTotal);
                UpdateTotal.Connection = conn;
                UpdateTotal.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static decimal CalculateIncome()
    {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I had before that included the WHERE clause in the command. With this code, it now only updates the the rows where it has an account name of "Savings," but it still sets the value in each of the rows to be the same for **AccountTotal**

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                AccountTotal = reader.GetDecimal(2); //Column in DB for Account Total
                AccountTotal += CalculateIncome();

                //Update Total
                SqlCeCommand UpdateTotal = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Accounts SET AccountTotal = @UpdatedTotal WHERE AccountName= @Savings", conn); // Error when using WHERE Clause "WHERE AccountName= @ avings"
                UpdateTotal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdatedTotal", AccountTotal);
                UpdateTotal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Savings", "Savings");
                UpdateTotal.Connection = conn;
                UpdateTotal.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Here is a visual as well for before and after the program is being run.

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After**
[image: After]

**Working Code**

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                AccountTotal = reader.GetDecimal(2); //Column in DB for Account Total
                //Console.WriteLine(AccountTotal);
                AccountTotal += CalculateIncome();
                //Console.WriteLine(AccountTotal);

                //Update Total
                SqlCeCommand UpdateTotal = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Accounts SET AccountTotal = @UpdatedTotal WHERE AccountName = @Savings AND AccountID = @ID", conn);
                UpdateTotal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdatedTotal", AccountTotal);
                UpdateTotal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Savings", "Savings");
                UpdateTotal.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", reader.GetInt32(0));
                UpdateTotal.Connection = conn;
                UpdateTotal.ExecuteNonQuery();

                AccountTotal = 0; //Reset
            }
```

Comment: Obviously your first problem comes from the fact you don't specify a `WHERE` clause, as you point out yourself. The `@` is separated from `Savings` in your comment, did you do that in the actual query as well?

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel I put the code that included a WHERE clause in the original post and I still have the problem where it updates all of the values to be the same.

Comment: @HighCore I am using this program with a database created in a ASP.NET MVC application by Entity Framework. Is there something else that I can do to make this easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two issues are:

1. It's updating all the rows to be the same value
   This is because there isn't a where clause in your update statement.
2. It's making the value double up.
   This is because of the line `AccountTotal += CalculateIncome();`
   What this does is in the first run make it be 100 and the second loop around it makes it be 200.

Comment: What is causing it to loop through twice on the same row instead of going to the next one? Does a change need to be made to the while loop to fix this?

Comment: I added in a where clause and now it only updates the values to be the same for every row that has an "AccountName" of Savings. Is it possible to make the query to be more specific to a single row? Or do I need to re-work my model for the database so that this can work?